# Why doesn't the depletion region completely vanishes in a p-n junction in forward biased condition?

Tags: solid-state-physics, potential-energy, semiconductor-physics

Can anyone explain why does the depletion region not vanish completely, but only shrinks, on forward bias?

Answer (score 1):

The PN junction properties depend highly on carrier injection rate. In case of low-level injection, i.e, injected minority carrier density is small compared to that of the majority carriers. Under this condition, the depletion region does not vanish. The increase in voltage may drop across the quasi-neutral regions which reduces the voltage dependency by the applied voltage across the junction.

However, under high-level injection (maybe a p$^+$n diode with high current injection) the minority carrier carrier concentration will be high that there is a gradient of energy in the quasi-neutral region. Effectively, the device does not have any rectifying property and it behaves as a resistor. The depletion region however will be very small that it can almost be ignored (no point in treating it as a pn junction rectifier).

The image show is simulated pn junction under low ((a) 10A/cm$^2$) and high ( (b) 10$^3$ (c) 10$^4$ A/cm$^2$) injection. You can see at the junction, the amount of band-bending becomes negligible (low built-in voltage).

[image: Source: SM Sze, Physics of Semiconductor devices, 3rd edition, Sec. 2.3.3]
Image Source: SM Sze, Physics of Semiconductor devices, 3rd edition, Sec. 2.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Depletion region is always present in the diode but its width depends on the nature of bias. If it is forward bias, the depletion region will be very thin but if the nature of bias is reverse, the width of depletion region will be very thick.

It is not possible to eradicate this depletion region completely even if the diode is highly forward bias and this depletion region is responsible to provide resistance to the external circuit although it is very low.

In more detail, majority carriers get some energy from the bias field, enabling them to go into the region and neutralize opposite charges. The more bias the more neutralization occurs. Hence, applying a positive voltage to the P-side with respect to the N-side narrows the depletion region.

That is why we consider forward bias diode like a normal conductor.

Comment: I believe Hari was asking *why* this is the case, rather than simply confirming that this is the case

Comment: Yeah The environmentalist

Comment: Is it due to the fact that the electrons get drifted past the depletion region rather than vanishing it due to electric filed created at the junction.

Comment: @Hari, I have edited my answer. Was it helpful?

Comment: Why don't you think that electrons could have actually gone into the depletion layer neutralising it and then move to p.In that case the whole depletion layer would have vanished.But that is not happening ,they just cross without vanishing them.The upcoming electrons could have actually neutralised all the n type positive ions at the depletion layer.But that does not happen why??

Comment: The complete nuetralisation never occurs, that's what gives rise to barrier potential. Also, what do you mean by "n type positive ions".